# SQL， Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql

```
SELECT LIFNR,
 SUM(CASE WHEN  UPPER([WAERS])='USD' THEN ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),DMBTR)* (-1),2)
               WHEN UPPER(WAERS)='USD' THEN ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),DMBTR),2) 
               ELSE ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),DMBTR),2)
               END)
AS 'AMOUNT'
FROM tbl_BSAK
GROUP BY LIFNR;
```

Hi, everyone.

I just wrote a piece of code and I keep getting the error message saying 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' I'm sure it's simple fix, but I have spent way too much time troubleshooting...

Please help me!!!!Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Some value in DMBTR is not convertible to a number

Comment: There must be data in the DMBTR column that cannot be converted to numeric. Not much else we can help you with.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the syntax, I'm assuming this is SQL Server.

If you want to find the offending value, do this:

```
select *
FROM tbl_BSAK
where isnumeric(DMBTR) = 0 and DMBTR is not null;
```

To fix the problem, do this:

```
SELECT LIFNR,
 SUM(CASE WHEN isnumeric(DMBTR) = 1and UPPER([WAERS])='USD' THEN ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),DMBTR)* (-1),2)
               WHEN isnumeric(DMBTR) = 1 and UPPER(WAERS)='USD' THEN ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),DMBTR),2) 
               when isnumeric(DMBTR) = 1 then ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),DMBTR),2)
               END)
AS 'AMOUNT'
FROM tbl_BSAK
GROUP BY LIFNR;
```